# Fetch records from mysql to a form with nodejs(expressjs)

Tags: node.js, express, ejs

Want to fetch records from mysql to a web form so that user can make changes and update it. Am fetching the records from different tables in the database.

**update.js**

```
    var express = require('express');
    var router = express.Router();
    var db     = require('./../db');

    router.get('/', function(req, res, next) {
      db.select('*').from('student').then(function(rows){
            res.render('update-student',{title:'Update Student',data:rows})
        });
    });

  router.get('/', function(req, res, next) {
      db.select('*').from('category').then(function(result){
            res.render('update-student',{title:'Update Student',edata:result})
        });
    });

    module.exports = router;
```

**update_student.ejs**

```
<select>
      <option></option>
      <% for (var i = 0; i < data.length; i++) {%>
     <option value=""><%= data[i].gender; %></option>
        <% }%>
 </select>

<select>
      <option></option>
      <% for (var i = 0; i < edata.length; i++) {%>
     <option value=""><%= edata[i].cat_name; %></option>
        <% }%>
 </select>
```

I had this erorr "**edata is not defined**"

Please any help

Answer (score 3, accepted):

The problem is that when you create a route, the first occurence will happen, the others won't if they have the same path. In your example you're stating that youre '/' will render update-student, but only the first one will happen, and in the first one you're sending only the information from student

Essentially what I'm saying is: each route is a page. You have two routes, right? So they are two different pages! In your case they have the same path, so only the first one will render.

Here's my proposal to you:

**update.js**

```
var express = require('express'),
    router  = express.Router(),
    db      = require('./../db');

router.get('/', function(req, res, next) {

  var isFinishedCount = 1,
      student         = [],
      category        = [];

  db.select('*').from('student').then(function(rows){
    student = rows;
    isFinished();
  });

  db.select('*').from('category').then(function(rows){
    category = rows;
    isFinished();
  });

  function isFinished(){
    if(isFinishedCount == 0){
      res.render('update-student',{
        title:'Update Student',
        data: {
          student : student,
          category: category
        }
      });
    }else{
      isFinishedCount--;
    }
  }

});

module.exports = router;
```

**update_student.ejs**

```
<select>
  <option></option>
  <% for (var i = 0; i < data.student.length; i++) {%>
    <option value=""><%= data.student[i].gender; %></option>
  <% }%>
</select>

<select>
  <option></option>
  <% for (var i = 0; i < data.category.length; i++) {%>
    <option value=""><%= data.category[i].cat_name; %></option>
  <% }%>
</select>
```

The code isn't tested, I'm sorry I just wanted to write it to you.

**Here's the break-down:**
In router we are declaring three variables. isFinishedCount is for our asynchronous calls to the db to fetch student and category, because those two calls to the db will happen in their own time and once each is finished we test if we can render the page, thats why we call isFinished() after each successful db call. I've never used the db calls like you're doing so I'm just copying your code and adapting.

Now, the result we put in two variables, student and category, so that later on we can render the page and we give them to data, so when in .ejs you're fetching the data that you've just acquired you will have them in data:

```
data - student
     - category
```

This provides you with a small "box" where you can put all the information you need, so later on you case use the same model for your other pages. This way you'll always know that your data will be inside "data".

Again sorry if there is any error, I didn't have a chance to test it I had to write it on the go, I'll check back again when I can in a few hours and test the code if I get the chance.

Happy coding!

Comment: I hope you understood why it works and what you were doing wrong :)

Comment: Yea I do understand. Thanks